# textarea10t0 disturbing weird id that don't work

Tags: php

This is really weird, but having a 0 at the end of "textarea10t0" makes it so it won't work when you set try to set the rows for the textarea. Literally, changing the ending to anything else, and it would've work. Am I going insane?

```
$textareaID = "textarea10t1";
<textarea id = '$textareaID' placeholder = 'Type something' onkeydown = \"test('editNotifyCommentSecond.php','{$outputID}', '{$textareaID}')\">$notifyComment</textarea>

<script>
//code
document.getElementById("textarea10t0").rows = 50; 
</script>
```

Comment: looks like a js issue not a php one

Comment: Where are the PHP opening/closing tags?

Comment: are you setting that element to 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the closing tag for php and the echo statement for the HTML with embeded php vars. Also, in the example above, your `id` in the `textarea` does not match the js `id`. If you change the html `id` to have a 0 at the end, you also need to change the js code.

```
<?php
$textareaID = "textarea10t0";
echo "<textarea id = '$textareaID' placeholder = 'Type something' onkeydown = \"test('editNotifyCommentSecond.php','{$outputID}', '{$textareaID}')\">$notifyComment</textarea>"
?>
<script>
//code
document.getElementById("textarea10t0").rows = 50; 
</script>
```